# How to get video src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get the src attribute of a video tag, but something is wrong:

```
<video id="vdisk" controls poster="placeh/02.jpg">
    <source src="placeh/01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var a = $("#vdisk").attr("src");
console.log(a); // undefined
```

Comment: You may want to use the `currentSrc` property.

Answer (score 4):

Use this.

```
document.getElementById("vdisk").getElementsByTagName("source")[SourceIndex].src
```

Where `SourceIndex` is the index of the source tag in case of multple source elements.

Comment: `ReferenceError: SourceIndex is not defined`

Comment: Yes i mean in case you have multiple sources, provide the index of that.

Answer (score 2):

As `source` is descendant of `#vdisk`, try this :-

```
var a = $("#vdisk source").attr("src");
console.log(a);
```

[Reference](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

Comment: Note that this may not be the source that is playing if more than one is present.

Answer (score 2):

The `currentSrc` property will get the `src` of whichever `<source>` is used for the video.

In your case, there's only one `<source>`, so "placeh/01.mp4" is the only possible value of the video's `currentSrc` (unless there's some other issue).

Note that this isn't a jQuery property. You have to convert the jQuery object to a DOM element in order to use it.

```
var a = $("#vdisk").get(0).currentSrc;
console.log(a); // "placeh/01.mp4"
```

Comment: Or use `.prop('currentSrc')`

Comment: i am sorry to ask this but in th OP there is no question what so ever asking for the src of the playing,,the OP simply stated that ***I need to get src attribute of a video tag***

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = $("#vdisk").find('source').attr("src");
console.log(a); // undefined
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id="vdisk" controls poster="placeh/02.jpg">
  <source src="placeh/01.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
js
```

Use [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

> Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Comment: Note that this may not be the source that is playing if more than one is present.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an attribute of `#vdisk`.  You have to access the inner element like this: `$("#vdisk").children("source").attr("src")`

Comment: Note that this may not be the source that is playing if more than one is present.

Answer (score 0):

you have to get the element "source" ,which have attribute "src"

Comment: What does this answer add over the other existing answers detailing the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

How about `$.each($("#id").get,function(){})`

```js
$.each($('#vdisk').get(),function(index, element)
{
  console.log(element.paused)
  //if(!element.paused) console.log(element.attr("src")) or something...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<video id="vdisk" controls poster="http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/images/img/homepage/87357.jpg">
  <source src="http://texasmotherfriendly.org/video/Childrens_Courtyard_640x360.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution ..

```
$("#vdisk source").attr("src")
```

Comment: What does this answer add over the other existing answers detailing the same thing?