# How to get src attribute inside source element that is inside a video element?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to retrieve the src attribute from a source element that is also inside a video element.

```
<video controls>
          <source src="img/Film/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          <source src="img/Film/vid.mp4" type="video/ogg" />
          Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get video src attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37670924/how-to-get-video-src-attribute)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get video tag src using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22241968/how-to-get-video-tag-src-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can select each `source` element in the `video` with `querySelectorAll` and map through the list to extract the `src` property:

```js
const sources = [...video.querySelectorAll('source')].map(e => e.src)

console.log(sources)
```

```html
<video controls id="video">
          <source src="img/Film/vid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          <source src="img/Film/vid.mp4" type="video/ogg" />
          Your browser does not support HTML video.
</video>
```